# Restarting a Linux Server via Web Browser (PHP)

Tags: php, linux, web

After opening and reading every result on Google, I figured it's time to make my own thread somewhere. *I am sorry that I need to ask a question that's already been asked before, I cannot stress this enough, but I have no other option as no other question asked has helped me achieve what my goal is.*

I'm trying to setup a means of rebooting/doing other system functions through a web interface powered by HTML (for the buttons/text) and PHP (for the execution of the aforementioned functions).

I'm unable to get this to work. I've read that I need to add the web user to the sudoers file, and I've tried. I'm running Nginx on my server, how do I add the user to the sudoers in my case?

Also, I'm aware of the security risks.

The following is what I have so far:

**HTML (index.html):**

```
<body>

<h3>Restart</h3>
<p>
<form action="restart.php" method="get">
  <input type="submit" value="Press me.">
</form>
</p>

</body>
```

**PHP (restart.php):**

```
<?php
echo "This is a test";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo shell_exec('ifconfig');
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Restarting server...";
exec ('/usr/bin/sudo /etc/init.d/portmap restart');
shell_exec("/sbin/reboot");
exec("/sbin/reboot");
system("/sbin/reboot");
?>
```

Mind you that here, I only have so many things attempting to execute, so that I make sure I hit the target when one of them works, if that makes sense. The IFConfig is just a test to make sure that it's actually able to execute.

**Sudoers:**

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
www-data reboot = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

This is all on Ubuntu 14.04 LEMP.

Comment: You're not using `sudo` to run `/sbin/reboot`.

Comment: And you haven't given it permission to run `/etc/init.d/portmap` in the `sudoers` file.

Comment: Why don't you install something like `Webmin` instead of rolling your own solution?

Comment: if you're rebooting the server, why bother trying to restart the portmapper? It'd be killed along with the rest of the system when it's rebooted.

Comment: (Re my edit: I recommend against asking people not to comment on the security risks. It is good that you are aware of this, but there may be one that you've not thought of.)

Comment: @Barmar My purpose for doing this is so that I'm able to run various system functions that aren't necessarily a security hazard. While Rebooting may be a small part of what I'm trying to achieve in the end, I don't think Webmin would fully meet the needs I would have for it -- as far as running custom scripts go. Is Webmin capable of doing this?

Comment: Yes, Webmin allows you to add custom scripts: http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Custom_Commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can do this either by editing your sudoers file :**

*Sudoers:*

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

The **first ALL is for the hostname** if you're hostname is **not 'reboot'** I advise you to **keep ALL as it will work in any hostname**. That's why it doesn't seem to work on your server

*restart.php*

```
exec('sudo /sbin/reboot');
```

**Or without editing your sudoers file.**

- First create a file where you're gonna store you're root password

*~/password* :

```
myrootpassword
```

- Second run any command you want while being root from php file (don't forget to specify the file which store your password)

*phpfile.php  :*

```
exec('sudo -u root -S /sbin/reboot < ~/password');
```

Comment: Why not use the sudoers file ? Seems silly having your root password lying around, You may as well just use the root account if you do ..

Comment: @exussum I prefer to give him the choice with all possibilities

Comment: While this is quite a different approach, I still tried it just to see if it'd work -- it didn't work for me.

Comment: Refreshed, saw your updated post. That worked! Awesome, thanks @KhaledBentoumi. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 www-data reboot = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

this means you dont need a password when running sudo, not that the command runs as sudo when ever run by that user.

The answer is to use `sudo /sbin/reboot` as the command

Comment: I've attempted this, but to no avail. No difference was made when I modified the PHP file and ran it in my browser.

Comment: `exec whoami` and check that, Everything seems set up for this to work

Answer (score -8):

You can use puty. I think using php is not a good plan.

Comment: Robert, You do not address OPs problem here.